# Why can't mv deal with existence of same-name directory in destination?

Tags: linux, mv, coreutils

`mv` can't move a directory to a destination with a same-name directory:

```
$ mv fortran/ imperative_PLs/
mv: cannot move ‘fortran/’ to ‘imperative_PLs/fortran’: Directory not empty
```

1. Why does `mv` not work in this case? Can that be explained from the system calls `mv` invokes? (Compare to `rsync` which can)
2. Why is `mv` designed to not work in this case? What is the rationale or point?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `mv` doesn't work in this case because it's not been designed to do so. The system calls are (probably) either

   - Move to same filesystem: `rename` (originally `link` and `unlink`)
   - Move across filesystems: recursive file copy followed by recursive `unlink`
2. Opinion: I think it's not so much that it was designed *not* to work, as it wasn't designed to handle this use case. For a "simple" tool that's intended to do one thing well you'd need to provide a set of switches to indicate to `mv` which of these action paths to take:

   - To bail with an error, as in the current implementation
   - To merge, bailing with an error if a file already exists
   - To merge, replacing any target files that already exist

If the merge/replace action is what you want, you can implement it easily enough with `cp` followed by `rm`, or by using one of the file tree copying utilities `tar`, `pax`, etc.

Comment: Thanks. (1) Does `rm` call `rmdir()` besides `rename()`?  (2) "Move to same filesystem: rename (originally link and unlink)", what do you mean by "originally link and unlink"? (3) When Move across filesystems, why "recursive file copy followed by recursive unlink"?

Comment: my typo. I meant `mv` instead of `rm`.

Comment: @Tim: Within the same filesystem, `mv` uses *only* `rename()`. Between filesystems, `mv` does essentially the same as `cp -r` (but beware handling of special files like symlinks, devices, etc. which are, traditionally, not handled well by `cp -r`) followed by `rm -r`, so yes, it uses `rmdir()` in that mode.

Answer (score 10):

`mv` and `rsync` are not similar programs.  In particular, `mv` is often attempting to simply rename objects.  If it's in the same filesystem, it does not copy the contents at all.

If you didn't already have `imperative_PLs/fortran`, then `mv` would take the existing `fortran` directory and rename it to that point in the tree.

But you already have a directory (with contents) at that location.  Because a name can only reference a single object, the existing directory would have to be either removed or renamed.  `mv` assumes you don't want to do either and aborts.

`rsync` instead copies the individual files and other contents inside `fortran` and puts them into the existing `imperative_PLs/fortran` directory.

Think of it as `rename` instead, and the behavior might seem more understandable.

Answer (score 7):

`mv` is actually `rename` under the cover.

If you move a file to another file, `mv` assumes you know what you are doing and overwrite the destination file.

If you move a directory to another directory, `mv` assumes you want to keep the basename of your original directory and create it on the target directory. If there is not yet a directory with that name on the destination side, or if a directory with that name exists but is empty, the operation succeeds.

However, if the target directory already exists and is not empty, this is no more a `rename` but that should be a recursive file and directory removal. `rename` isn't designed to do it so it fails, `mv` doesn't go further as it assumes you didn't want to do it and fails too.

Comment: Thanks. Does `rm` call `rmdir()` besides `rename()`?

Comment: @Tim: `rm` doesn't ever call `rename()`. But it does call `rmdir()` when given the `-r` option.

Comment: @Gun: My typo. I meant `mv` instead of `rm`.

Comment: `mv` calls `rmdir()` only if the source and destination file systems are differents. One reason is it is not anymore the same inode that has a new path.

Answer (score 3):

The error message when moving between filesystems is slightly more verbose:

```
# mv a/foo b/bar
mv: inter-device move failed: 'a/foo' to 'b/bar/foo'; unable to remove target: Directory not empty
```

So it's not trying to merge directories like you seem to expect, instead it's removing the target before renaming the source; and removing for directories only works when it's empty.

In terms of syscalls, within the same filesystem, it's just `rename()`

```
rename("a/foo", "a/bar/foo")            = -1 ENOTEMPTY (Directory not empty)
```

When moving between filesystems, it's first `rename()` detecting this case and them a simple attempt at `rmdir()`.

```
rename("a/foo", "b/bar/foo")            = -1 EXDEV (Invalid cross-device link)
rmdir("b/bar/foo")                      = -1 ENOTEMPTY (Directory not empty)
```

`mv` could make more of an effort but it doesn't want to. ;)

Comment: thanks. does `mv` call `rmdir()`? I tried one with `strace -e trace=file` on `mv`, `rmdir()` doesn't come up.

Comment: only when crossing filesystem boundaries, otherwise I guess it's `rename()` handling it internally

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the content inside of a dir with another, you can use

```
mv --backup=simple src dest
```

Which will rename the `dest` to `dest~` and move the `src` to `dest`.